# How to collapse unique duplicate columns to unique columns in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

**Solution**

I went with the solutions provided by @MauritsEvers and @akrun below.

**Question**

For a data frame, I want to keep only 1 column of each set of duplicate columns. In addition, the column that is kept takes on a name that is a concatenation of all column names in the set of duplicate columns. There are multiple sets of duplicate columns in the data frame. The data frame contains tens of thousands of columns, so using a for loop might take too much time.

I have tried a combination of using the duplicate(), summary(), aggregate(), lapply(), apply(), and using for loops.

Input data frame (df_in):

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1
0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0
```

Output data frame (df_out):

```
0-2-5 1-4 3 6 7
0     1   0 1 1
0     1   1 0 0
1     0   0 1 0
```

Comment: Numbers as column names in a `data.frame` are awkward. Is that really how your data looks like? If so, please provide sample data using `dput`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers the data does have numbers as column names. Should I modify the column names by prefixing with an underscore?

Comment: It's best to include sample data using e.g. `dput`, to avoid confusion. Either way, I've added a solution below, please take a look.

Comment: @akrun it shouldn't be the same. I corrected the df_in data frame as per your remark.

Comment: @spence I changed the data.  It is giving the expected output as showed in hyour post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following in base R

1. Get indices of identical columns

   ```
   idx <- split(seq_along(names(df)), apply(df, 2, paste, collapse = "_"))
   ```
2. Sort indices from low to high

   ```
   idx <- idx[order(sapply(idx, function(x) x[1]))]
   ```
3. Names of `idx` as concatentation of column names

   ```
   names(idx) <- sapply(idx, function(x) paste(names(df)[x], collapse = "_"))
   ```
4. Create final `matrix`

   ```
   sapply(idx, function(x) df[, x[1]])
   #     col0_col2_col5 col1_col4 col3_col6 col7
   #[1,]              0         1         1    1
   #[2,]              0         1         0    0
   #[3,]              1         0         1    0
   ```

Note that the resulting object is a `matrix`, so if you need a `data.frame` simply cast `as.data.frame`.

---

### Sample data

I've changed your sample data slightly to not have numbers as column names.

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "col0 col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0", header = T)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`.  We `gather` the data into 'long' format, conver the 'value' into a string, grouped by 'value', `paste` the 'key' column together, separate the rows of 'value' and then `spread` the 'value' column to get the expected output

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df_in) %>% 
   group_by(key) %>%
   summarise(value = toString(value)) %>% 
   group_by(value) %>% 
   summarise(key = paste(key, collapse="-")) %>% 
   separate_rows(value) %>% 
   group_by(key) %>%
   mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
   spread(key, value) %>%
   select(-n)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  `0-2-5` `1-4` `3`   `6`   `7`  
#  <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 0       1     0     1     1    
#2 0       1     1     0     0    
#3 1       0     0     1     0
```

---

Or another option with `tidyverse` would be

```
t(df_in) %>%
    as.data.frame %>%
    mutate(grp = group_indices(., V1, V2, V3)) %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number() - 1) %>% 
    group_split(grp, keep = FALSE) %>% 
    map_dfc(~ .x %>% 
           mutate(rn = str_c(rn, collapse="-")) %>% 
           slice(1)  %>% 
           gather(key, val, -rn) %>% 
           rename(!! .$rn[1] := val) %>% 
           select(ncol(.)))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  `0-2-5`   `3`   `7`   `6` `1-4`
#    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1       0     0     1     1     1
#2       0     1     0     0     1
#3       1     0     0     1     0
```

---

Or we can also do this with `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(as.data.table(t(df_in))[, grp := .GRP, .(V1, V2, V3)][, 
     c(.SD[1], cn = paste(.I-1, collapse="-")) , .(grp)],
      id.var = c('cn', 'grp')), variable ~ cn, value.var = 'value')[, 
        variable := NULL][]
#    0-2-5 1-4 3 6 7
#1:     0   1 0 1 1
#2:     0   1 1 0 0
#3:     1   0 0 1 0
```

#### data

```
df_in <- structure(list(`0` = c(0L, 0L, 1L), `1` = c(1L, 1L, 0L), `2` = c(0L, 
 0L, 1L), `3` = c(0L, 1L, 0L), `4` = c(1L, 1L, 0L), `5` = c(0L, 
 0L, 1L), `6` = c(1L, 0L, 1L), `7` = c(1L, 0L, 0L)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```